# Using the accelerometer to know and react to speed of phone in motion (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I'm a newbie. I just want the phone to react to movement through speed.

Like:

If speed > 20 mph

```
   Display Text
```

and I also want it set off as a background process so that it always checks and reacts when speed exceeds. Thank you.